# vline add remote stream for callee fail

Tags: webrtc, vline

I am trying to use your api in a custom app with imported users.
Everything works fine (auth_token, login, call initiation) , but when the callee should get a response and add the remotestream nothing happens. no errors get shown in the console.
I would appreciate if someone takes a look at the code and tells me what i m missing.
I tried the vline demo at  https://freeofcinema.vline.com and it worked with the same browsers and conditions between the two computers. In my app it is a http , but i tried it also with https, and the same problem came up. This is some simplified code i used to test the api.

```
var Streams = [];
var Vsession = null;
var Vline = (function(){
    var Client;
    var authToken;
    var service_id = 'freeofcinema'; 
    var profile = null;
    var Person;
    var Calls = [];

var onMessage = function(event){
    //alert('message');
    var msg = event.message, sender = msg.getSender();
    console.log(sender.getDisplayName() +'sais: '+ msg.getBody());
    console.log(event);
}
var onMediaSession = function(event){
    console.log(event); 
    var mediaSession = event.target; 
    InitSession(mediaSession);
}

function Call(mediaSession) {
    mediaSession.
    on('change', alert_info);
}

function alert_info(b){
    console.log(b);
}

function InitSession(mediaSession){
    mediaSession.on('mediaSession:addRemoteStream', function(event) {
        alert('addRemoteStream');
    });
    mediaSession.on('mediaSession:addLocalStream', function(event) {
        alert('addLocalStream');
    });
    mediaSession.on('mediaSession:removeLocalStream mediaSession:removeRemoteStream', function(event) {
        console.log('removedStream');
    });
    Calls.push(new Call(mediaSession));
}

return {
    init : function(){
        if(profile){
            return;
        }
        profile = {
            "displayName" : //some getusrname function...
        }; 
        $.post('vtoken.php',{//get auth token
            id : Comm.Voip_user().id
        },function(data){
            authToken = data;
            Client = vline.Client.create({
                "serviceId": service_id,
                "ui" : true
            });
            Client.on('recv:im', onMessage , this);
            Client.on('add:mediaSession', onMediaSession, this);
            Client.on('login', function(e) {
                Vsession = e.target;
                //alert('loged in');
            });
            Client.login(service_id, profile, authToken); 
        });   
    },
    getPerson : function(id){//id of user to call
        if(Vsession){
            Vsession.getPerson(id).
            done(function(person){
                Person = person;
                Vsession.startMedia(id);
            });
        } 
    }
}
}());
```

Thank you for your response.

I tried with one user from the app, and another from the https://freeofcinema.vline.com, and the same problem occured. Also the call (in pending state) gets terminated after a short while..

Answer (score 1):

When passing ui:true when creating the client, you do not have to handle the media sessions yourself. Just comment the line

```
Client.on('add:mediaSession', onMediaSession, this);
```

and it should just work.